# Using Maven artifact in Google Cloud Docker build

Tags: maven, docker, google-cloud-platform

I have a google cloud container build with the following steps

1. gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn to run a mvn clean package cmd
2. gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker to create a docker image

My docker image includes and will run tomcat.

Both these steps work fine independently.

How can I copy the artifacts built by step 1 into the correct folder of my docker container? I need to move either the built wars or specific lib files from step 1 to the tomcat dir in my docker container.

Echoing out the /workspace and /root dir in my Dockerfile doesn't show the artifacts. I think I'm misunderstanding this relationship.

Thanks!

Edit:

I ended up changing the Dockerfile to set the `WORKDIR to /workspace`

and

`COPY /{files built by maven} {target}`

Comment: Shouldn't your dockerfile copy all the resources it needs during the build step? You can get a dockerfile runner as a maven plugin.

Comment: Doesn't multistage build help you? https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/

Comment: i was unsure of the source path to use when copying files in the docker build step, since echoing out /workspace didn't show anything. however, setting the workdir to /workspace and copying seemed to work

Answer (score 0):

The *working directory* is a persistent volume mounted in the **builder** containers, by default under `/workdir`. You can find more details in the documentation here https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/build-config#dir

I am not sure what is happening in your case. But there is an example with a Maven step and a Docker build step in the documentation of the `gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn` builder. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/mvn/examples/spring_boot. I suggest you compare with your files.

If it does not help, could you share your `Dockerfile` and `cloudbuild.yaml`. Please make sure you remove any sensitive information.

Also, you can inspect the working directory by running the build locally https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/build-debug-locally#preserve_intermediary_artifacts